# Why does my program stop running and does not return error?

Tags: java, io, while-loop

I put the declaration in the while loop, and the program would not running and also does not return any error. I suspect the while loop become an infinite loop.

```
                    try
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream (fileName));
                            Ship copyObject = (Ship) inputStream.readObject();
                            String nameCompany = copyObject.getCompanyName();

                            if (compName.equalsIgnoreCase(nameCompany)){
                                listShipName += (copyObject.getShipName() + ", ");
                                numberOfShip ++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    catch (EOFException e)
                    {
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

But if I put the declaration of input stream out of the while loop, the program runs successfully. Can someone explain why this happens?

```
                        try
                        {
                            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream (fileName));

                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {

                                Ship copyObject = (Ship) inputStream.readObject();
                                String nameCompany = copyObject.getCompanyName();

                                if (compName.equalsIgnoreCase(nameCompany)){
                                    listShipName += (copyObject.getShipName() + ", ");
                                    numberOfShip ++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        catch (EOFException e)
                        {
                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: Post the complete runnable example plzz

Comment: yeah! Your question seems to be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You're reopening your file on every iteration through the loop, which means you are only ever reading the first object from the file.  But you're reading the same object over and over again.

As well as opening your file only once, you really should try to detect the end of file without throwing an exception.  As a matter of style, exceptions should be thrown when things go wrong, not as a matter of course.

Answer (score 0):

Now I realize that in each iteration, I reopen the input stream, so the loop would not reach to the end of the file, and it becomes infinite.